# gallery with thumbs or simil with full width detail

Tags: width, lightbox2

I search a lightbox that have the detail of image in full width
 I try with fancybox and ightbox but the size of the image is static, I need the image is displayed in full width
Anyone can help me?

Comment: You need to use another size of image in order to use full width. Otherwise, resolution will be bad